# how to make a main content of a sidebar without make a new tab/refresh the page to linked file?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dashboard.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/463f6f67c2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="dashboard">
<h1>Halo,<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></h1>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Sidebar</h2>

    <ul><!--sidebar list-->
        <li><a href="#" id="home"><i class="fa-solid fa-house-user"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="petugas.php" target="main_body"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-tie"></i>Data Petugas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="kelas"><i class="fa-solid fa-users-rectangle"></i>Data Kelas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="siswa"><i class="fa-solid fa-money-check"></i>Data Siswa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="history pembayaran"><i class="fa-solid fa-clock"></i>History Pembayaran</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        </div>
</div>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    }else{
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

in this case if i click 'petugas' on sidebar the web making the new tab/window without the sidebar,i want the sidebar stay in the page and load the 'petugas.php' without make a new tab/window,just in the 'petugas' section

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be solved only by PHP.

PHP is executed server-sided. This means, the moment you see the page, all PHP is done. Calling another PHP script means calling a new page.

If you want to change content asynchronously on your page, you either need a different technology that works *after* the page is loaded, like JavaScript performing AJAX-Requests to another script and altering the HTML that has already been generated.
**Edit**: The answer by @Henrique shows methods for this approach.

Or you can "trick" this behaviour by loading everything upfront and hide the things you do not want to show from the beginning using CSS. Needless to say that this is not a good practice, but solves your question.

If you write each page yourself, you can put the sidebar to some sort of wrapper that loads with every page you link to. It will redraw on every link click, but it will be there for every page. And it seems the least complicated way for your situation.